# Hide Cardview & ImageView inside CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android-layout

Whenever I'll scroll my activity, I want toolbar should remain stable and else everything should go below the toolbar. I have used CollapsingToolbarLayout and  AppBarLayout, but still I'm not getting proper solution.

Here in this code, CircleImageView and CardView are comming above the toolbar while scrolling.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/contact_photo_height"
        android:elevation="8dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsideToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:title="back"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/verify_image"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
                app:title="back"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg4"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/cardView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" /> 
  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one of the most important property app:layout_behavior in card view.

1. If you want eveything else like cardview, circular ImageView and rest to scroll till toolbar then club them in Relative or LinearLayout and assign app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior".

   ```
   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
       android:id="@+id/cardView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
       app:cardElevation="5dp"
       app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
       app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

   <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
       android:layout_width="120dp"
       android:layout_height="120dp"
       android:elevation="8dp"
       android:src="@drawable/bg4"
       app:layout_anchor="@+id/cardView"
       app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />
    </LinearLayout>
   ```

Now, everything will just scroll properly. Hope it helps.